# C# Network Game Programming

Tags: c#, networking

What are some good resources for learning how to program applications that use networking C# (say a game)?

Comment: If you wanna do game programming change your title, they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For games I would surely recommend reading the [Networking for Game Programmers](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/) series by Glenn Fiedler - the code is in C++ though, but great general knowledge. As for C#, I would recommend going through the [Networking section](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?devarea=19) of the App Hub Education Catalog

**UPDATE**

I almost forgot the Shawn Hargreaves's Blog. The following [Blog Index](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/blogindex.html) organizes each of his posts by category. Scroll down till you get to the Networking Category.

Answer (score 2):

For game programming I think you should go with [**XNA**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791), there are tones of article in internet about it and networking,
you can see SO question for starting XNA: [Which book should read to start XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576893/xna-which-single-book-should-a-beginner-start-with)

**Edit:** But, for network programming, see [my question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036251/how-to-connect-to-modems-within-tcp-clients-in-multiple-port-or-other-way) people tried to answer my question provided really good samples (also my question contain it).

Answer (score 1):

For example:

- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/)
- [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/)
- [Programmer's Heaven](http://www.programmersheaven.com/)
- stackoverflow.com ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Marcel: I've looked at Codeproject and codeguru. I came up empty as far as a doable solution. I'll look at programmer's heaven?

@Saeed: Would it be difficult to convert an existing C# Forms application to XNA?

Comment: You should add these replies as comments and not as answers. If you add these as comments to someones answer, he/she will receive a notification, while this way they won't.

Comment: If you wanna program game use XNA, start learn it then move your current application, XNA is in C# so converting existence code is not hard see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx for start up.

Comment: I supposed that's the easiest then